# Perforce Recently Submitted Changelists Not Showing

Tags: perforce

For some reason, my most recently submitted Perforce changelists are not showing up in P4Win or P4V, but when I inspect the depot directly, I can see the files that I've added and on inspecting the source files that I changed, it contains the changes that would have been contained in the submitted changelists that do not show up.

I'm not sure how to either force/flush the database to show the changelists or how otherwise to recover these changelists.

Now, some more details on how this occurred:
I have my p4 depot on an external drive, and the p4 server running on a desktop, but over the weekend, I took the drive to another desktop while traveling, and used p4 server on that machine to set up the depot on the ext drive.

Now, the weird thing is, the submitted changelists contains 2 changelists that I made on one day during traveling, but the changelists from the second day of travel do not show up. However, as mentioned above, the actual files have been changed, and any new files that I added are present in the depot.

How can I recover these most recent changes?

Comment: Since the depot files are affected, changelist should be there AFAIK. Are you sure you are using correct filters for User, Workspace in P4V ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I was seeing the results with no filters set. (i.e. any users and workspaces), but I will double check once I am in front of it again.

Comment: Yup, no filters set. Another note, I'm not sure two servers were of the same version.

Comment: What output do you get if you run `p4 verify`?

Comment: I did p4 verify on one of my files, for one instance, and it lists the latest as revision 2838. I opened up the .cpp,v file, and here is what the top of that file looks like:`head     1.2852;
access   ;
symbols  ;
locks    ;comment  @@;


1.2852
date     2013.02.10.15.17.37;  author p4;  state Exp;
branches ;
next     1.2838;

1.2838
date     2013.01.29.15.07.39;  author p4;  state Exp;
branches ;
next     1.2835;` Please excuse the lack of spacing/formatting. I've never actually posted to stackoverflow before.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you're trying to accomplish by moving the hard drive from machine to machine, but perhaps the best thing you could do at this point is to contact Perforce Technical Support.