# P4V not seeing new submits after OS recovery

Tags: perforce

I've googled this, and saw that someone had a similar problem here -> [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14819512/perforce-recently-submitted-changelists-not-showing), but as luck would have it, unresolved.

I have an issue where my P4 client is not able to see or access any submitted files that are newer than 4 months old.

Background - My root directory/db files are on D drive which is undisturbed. I got a nasty virus yesterday, so I checked in all my workspace stuff and recovered to a December drive of my OS. Now that I've successfully booted up in my December version of my OS (where the same version P4V and P4A is already installed), my P4V is only able to see and access files up to 12/15/2015 - nothing after. The drive image I recovered from is dated 12/19/2016. Yet, I can physically inspect all my post Dec P4 checkins in the physical location of my DB on D drive. It's ALL THERE.

Here's really interesting info - out of curiosity, I recovered back to my Virus laden OS from yesterday. Opened up P4V, and it is able to see and access all my files up till my very last submitted file which was checked in yesterday.

Other important into
- The depot, stream, and workspace that my p4 is using is the same between my recovered Dec recovery OS, and yesterday's Virus laden OS. Nothing was ever changed in my P4 settings.

System info:

- Windows 10
- P4V and P4A - NTX64/2014.3/1007540 (for both my recovered windows image from Dec, and yesterday's virus laden windows)

P4 is my achilless heel. Help appreciated. I will not take offense if you explain things to me like a 3rd grader.

Cheers,
Paul

Comment: Perhaps, you used to have a server in a different location (your C:\ drive, maybe), and when you restored back to Dec 2015, you ended up resetting your P4V configuration (specifically, the P4PORT that is uses for its connection), so that it's pointing to that old server. Try (a) running 'p4 info' from the command line, and (b) in P4V, look in your "Connection" menu to see the settings that you are using for your P4V connection -- are you connecting to the server that you think you are?

Comment: Good observation, but the server is indeed installed in the exact same location, and the settings were never changed (99.999% sure). After taking a crash course on P4 (ugh), at this point, I feel somewhat confident that my issue has something to do with journal files and or checkpoints. That is what is different between my Dec install of P4 and my virus os install of P4, and this mismatch would fit my symptoms. These files don't live with the DB files on the other drive (I assumed it was a self contain package - not so). I'll update what I learn, and follow your suggestion if needed.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I used incorrect terminology in my original question. I had my depots on D drive and everything else in their default locations on C.

**Where I had it wrong**: in the belief that as long as I had my depot files backed up to a safe location, I was protected. There is more to it than that :|

**What went wrong**: When my PC crashed, I recovered to a 5 month earlier December version of my Windows install which means (obviously) I have December's install of P4 with database files only aware of files I checked in up to December. I did indeed have 1000s of files check in after Dec, all alive and intact, but P4 is simply unaware of it. An assumption (which I had) that P4 simply peeks into the Depots to stay up to date of their contents is an incorrect and dangerous one.

**To those who may benefit**: For those do-it-yourselfers, these are the 2 things in Perforce you should be backing up if you want to be able to do a full recovery later down the line when things go bad:

- **Database files**. By default, they live in the Perforce application’s “server” directory. For me, there are 67 database files in my C:\Program Files\Perforce\Server. They are all prefixed with db.* and it’s these files that P4 uses to “know” the current state of things, like, your changlists, checked-out files, all your workspaces and their settings, depots and their settings, etc, etc etc. Oh, and what files you even have in your depot! Unfortunately, when backing up database files, you can’t just copy/paste them, but must use command line commands to properly generate 2 other file types (journal, checkpoint) specifically for recovery purposes. It is these files that you'll generate new database files from in a recovery operation.
- **Depot directories**. Depots specify directory trees that your files get stored to, and checked out from when working in your workspace. Files stored here won’t be in their native format, and non-binary files will have their contents tweaked on top of that. Depot directory trees can be manually copied/paste to a backup location.

Proper backup/recovery information can be found [here](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.2/manuals/p4sag/chapter.backup.html). Like many things, it’s simple once you understand it, but reading this is a bit of a mouth full. It would have helped me to just see slightly fleshed out sample commands along with the reading material, so I’ve included some here. These are the bare minimum command line commands (plus other manual stuff), and will recover a checkpoint, not checkpoint + journal (again, take a look at the link to get a better understanding). Also, I would recommend practicing backup/recovery in a safe throw away environment (or throw away assets) to get the hang of this before doing it for real.

---------- Backup ------------

Despite all the material in the link, it only takes a bare minimum of 3 command line commands (plus other non-command stuff) to do a proper P4 backup, and 1 cmd (among other things) to recover on my end. Again this is only a partially fleshed out sample to illustrate what the command prompt portion of backup/recovery looks like. There is a little more to it than simply running these to get you where you want.

(note: On Windows, you may need to start a windows command prompt as administrator)

```
>p4 set P4USER=superuser_name
>p4 -q verify //...
>p4d -r "C:\Program Files\Perforce\Server" -jc <yourBackupDirectory>\<prefixOfYourChoosing>
```

---------- Recovery  ------------

```
>p4d -f -r "C:\Program Files\Perforce\Server" -jr <yourBackupDirectory>\<prefixYouChose>.ckp.1
```

In my case, I had to use the -f flag due to errors when not using it.

Cheers,

Paul W